# How to convert bufferarray back into audio

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object in memory with audio data stored as Uint8Array:

audioContent: { type: "Buffer", data: (361728) […] }

Basically - I'm not sure how to convert this back this into an audio stream and play it in a browser.

Approach I've tried:

```
<audio id="audio_player" src = ...>


<script>
  let audioElement = document.getElementById("audio_player");

  const blob = new Blob(trackData.audioContent.data);
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audioElement.src = url;

</script>
```

The truth is I have no proper concept of what's needed to make this work beyond the high level 'turning the array into an encoded stream'

I'm looking for code examples I can use to understand how to do this.

*EDIT*
Thanks to all for sharing their code and suggestions.
Going through the suggestions firefox wasn't happy with the encoding.
I went back to square 1 - encoded the source audio as Base64 and played it like so in a JS function, with *trackData* being the base64 data.

```
  var audio = new Audio("data:audio/mp3;base64," + trackData);
  audio.play();
```

Comment: What is the mime type of the uint8array binary content?

Comment: Hi. The mime type is mp3

Comment: By the way, how do you know that the audio data is an `uint8array` within the `json`?

Comment: good question lol - best guess based on the int range being between 0 and 255, e.g.,         "data": [
            255,
            243,
            196,
            0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a json array of unsigned 8 bit integers representing audio data, initialize a [**`Blob`** <sup>[mdn]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#examples) with this array.

```js
<audio id="audio_player"></audio>
<script>
  let audioElement = document.getElementById("audio_player");
  const blob = new Blob(trackData.audioContent.data, { type: "audio/mpeg" });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audioElement.src = url;
</script>
```

Comment: actually - I see you used mpeg. I used mp3 (which didn't work). I shall try that.

Comment: Thanks Chuk! Appreciated. This is exactly the step I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think to play audio from a `Uint8Array` representing audio data in a browser, you can use the Web Audio API.

I add an example code below:

```
<audio id="audio_player" controls></audio>

<script>
  // Assuming trackData.audioContent.data is your Uint8Array
  const audioData = trackData.audioContent.data;
  const arrayBuffer = audioData.buffer;

  // Create a Blob from the ArrayBuffer
  const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'audio/wav' }); // Adjust the MIME type based on your audio format

  // Create a URL for the Blob
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const audioElement = document.getElementById('audio_player');
  audioElement.src = url;
  audioElement.play();
</script>
```

This example assumes that your audio data is in a common audio format like `WAV`.

You can adjust the MIME type in the Blob constructor based on your actual audio format.